# Подключение всех модулей проекта через один модуль - "проводник"

Tags: node.js, модули

Когда проект начинает разрастаться, появляется много разичных модулей. Модули по одинаковым направлениеям, приходится группировать по пакам, например:
"Логин", "Работа с БД", "GETзапросы"  и т.д. Переодически структура меняется. В связи с чем, приходится просматривать все файлы и 
изменять пути подключения модулей. Для решения этого неудобства, я решил, сначала подключать все модули к одному файлу, назовем его `tube.js`, а 
потом уже `tube.js` подключать к необходимым модулям.
Получилось приблизительно так:

файл `one.js`

```
var d = 10;
module.exports = d;
```

файл `doSome.js`

```
function doSome(i){
    console.log(i)
}
module.exports = doSome;
```

файл `tube.js`

```
const oneJs = require("./one.js");
const doSome = require("./doSome.js");

module.exports.oneJs = oneJs;
module.exports.doSome = doSome;
```

файл `start.js`

```
const oneJs = require("./tube.js").oneJs;
const doSome = require("./tube.js").doSome;

console.log(oneJs);
doSome("very good");
```

По задумке, в случае изменения структуры проекта изменить путь всего лишь в одном файле `tube.js`. Данная схема в тестовом режиме работает отлично.
Но вот когда, я попытался прикрутить ее к проекту, начали возникать проблемы. В модули стали выбрасывать исключения, что тот или иной модуль `is not a function`.

К файлу 'tube.js' подключено около 30 модулей, столько же соответственно он "раздает". Модули, естественно, в разы объемнее, чем тестовые примеры. На сколько я смог понять, файл 'tube.js' не успевает подключить все модули, прежде, чем отдать их....

Как решить проблему? У кого есть какие мысли?

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы разобрался. Проблемы была в структуре модуля-проводника `tube.js`. В примере, он у меня выглядит так:

```
const oneJs = require("./one.js");
const doSome = require("./doSome.js");

module.exports.oneJs = oneJs;
module.exports.doSome = doSome;
```

Первое, что я сделал  - это начал экспортировать модули сразу же после их подключения. Вот так:

```
const oneJs = require("./one.js");
module.exports.oneJs = oneJs;

const doSome = require("./doSome.js");
module.exports.doSome = doSome;
```

Второе, на что нужно обратить внимание, это - если, например,  модуль `one.js` для своей работы требует подключения модуля `doSome.js` (а в моей схеме, он это делает через `tube.js`), то к моменту, когда модуль-проводник будет подключать `one.js`, модуль `doSome.js` должен быть уже подключен. Т.е., в таком случае, код что выше работать не будет. А будет работать такой код:

```
const doSome = require("./doSome.js");
module.exports.doSome = doSome;

const oneJs = require("./one.js");
module.exports.oneJs = oneJs;
```